# How to select certain rows with specific number sequences

Tags: r

I would like to select certain rows in the dataframe X that only contain certain numbers (order does not matter) and not others:

```
A   1,  2,  3,  4,  9,  11, 27
B   1,  3,  4,  9           
C   2,  5,  8,  12, 42, 45  
D   3,  1,  9,  4
```

In this case I would like to select rows with numbers `1,3,4,9` in any order, but cannot contain any other numbers. Which would give me Rows `B` and `D`.
How do I do that in R?

I have tried `x[which(x=="1,3,4,9")]` but that would take order into account.

Thanks

Comment: How can those be in a dataframe. Dataframes are "rectangular".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mcve] and follow our guide how to [ask an awesome question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It makes life easier for us and improves your chances of getting an answer

Comment: `x == "1,3,4,9"` would compare entries in `x` **with character string `"1,3,4,9"`**, not with individual numbers `1,3,4,9`.

Comment: I collapsed the numbers for each row into one cell seperated by "," so I can detect different sequences

Comment: In that case you should show them in quotes to indicate that they are a single cell. Also, are there spaces? What you show, `1,  2,  3, `... with one or two space separations depending on number of digits is pretty different from `"1,2,3"`, which is what "collapsed into one cell separated by ','" implies. Best would be if you used `dput()` to share your example so the exact structure is preserved and it is copy pasteable.

Comment: The problem I have is that it is in a dataframe, column 1 are case numbers (1,2,3...etc), column 2 are the sequences for each case number (1,3,4,9). BUT column 2 are in character format...

Comment: @Oorangy As Gregor already said in the comment above, please use `dput()` to share your example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the elements of a list that *only* contain 1, 3, 4, 9?  I'll assume x is a list

```
x <- list(
'A' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 11, 27),
'B'=c( 1, 3, 4, 9),
'C'=c( 2, 5, 8, 12, 42, 45),
'D'=c( 3, 1, 9, 4 )
)
```

Try `Filter(function(x) length(setdiff(x, c(1,3,4,9))) == 0, x)`

which will handle any number of replicates and select `x` which contains subsets of 1, 3, 4, and 9.
or

`Filter(function(x) setequal(x, c(1,3,4,9)), x)`

which also handles any number of replicates, but will reject sets not containing all 4 numbers.

You can use array indices:

`x[sapply(x, setdiff, c(1,3,4,9))]`.

You can also look into the `%in%` operator, which is a special call to match: `!any(is.na(match(x, c(1,3,4,9)))`.

```
x[sapply(lapply(x, `%in%`, c(1,3,4,9)), all)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! The problem I have is that it is in a dataframe, column 1 are case numbers (1,2,3...etc), column 2 are the sequences for each case number (1,3,4,9). BUT column 2 are in character format...

Comment: Sorry I am new to R, still trying to figure out how to display my data correctly on here..